# how to use python zipfile to append comment for a zip file?

Tags: python, comments, python-zipfile

```
    $ echo "short"|zip -z test.zip
    enter new zip file comment (end with .):
    $ md5sum test.zip
    48da9079a2c19f9755203e148731dae9  test.zip
    $ echo "longlong"|zip -z test.zip
    current zip file comment is:
    short
    enter new zip file comment (end with .):
    $ md5sum test.zip
    3618846524ae0ce51fbc53e4b32aa35b  test.zip
    $ echo "short"|zip -z test.zip
    current zip file comment is:
    longlong
    enter new zip file comment (end with .):
    root@Debian:~# md5sum test.zip
    48da9079a2c19f9755203e148731dae9  test.zip
    $ echo "longlong"|zip -z test.zip
    current zip file comment is:
    short
    enter new zip file comment (end with .):
    $ md5sum test.zip
    3618846524ae0ce51fbc53e4b32aa35b  test.zip
    $
    $
    $ cat test.py
    #/usr/bin/env python
    #coding: utf-8

    import zipfile
    import subprocess

    zip_name = 'test.zip'

    def add_comment(zip_name, comment):
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, 'a') as zf:
            zf.comment = comment

    add_comment(zip_name, "short")
    print subprocess.Popen(['md5sum', zip_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0],
    add_comment(zip_name, "longlong")
    print subprocess.Popen(['md5sum', zip_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0],
    add_comment(zip_name, "short")
    print subprocess.Popen(['md5sum', zip_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0],
    add_comment(zip_name, "longlong")
    print subprocess.Popen(['md5sum', zip_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0],
    $
    $ python test.py 
    48da9079a2c19f9755203e148731dae9  test.zip
    3618846524ae0ce51fbc53e4b32aa35b  test.zip
    89c2038501f737991ca21aa097ea9956  test.zip
    3618846524ae0ce51fbc53e4b32aa35b  test.zip
```

At shell env, the fist time and the third time, "test.zip" md5 values are the same,
the second time and the forth time, "test.zip" md5 values are the same, but when i use
python zipfile, the result is not like that.
How can I do this with the Python `zipfile` module?

Answer (score 2):

The [`zipfile.ZipFile()` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile) has a [`comment` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.comment) you can set.

Open the file in append mode, alter the comment, and it'll be written out when closed:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('test.zip', 'a') as testzip:
    testzip.comment = 'short'
```

When you use a `ZipFile` as a context manager, like a regular file it'll automatically be closed when the `with` block is exited.